# how can i use google map api in iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone

I need to show driving directions, and walking directions in map view. There is now availability in iphone map kit. how can I use google map api in web view. can I interact google map api with iphone

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone.html).